# How do I create a rotating wheel/image in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm a beginner app developer. I want to make an app with a spinning/rotating wheel in it, like the one in trivia crack. My idea was to use an UIImage with holds an image of a wheel. When the user taps the image, I want to let the image spin. This isn't difficult for me, but the difficult part for me is to let the wheel spin to a certain category on the wheel. Do you guys have any idea how I should do this. I thought that I could work with degrees and angles, but I don't know how to work with degrees in `swift`.
I hope that some of you can help me!

Comment: What do you mean `spin to certain category`? Do you want to rotate image specific radius?

Comment: The wheel is divides in catagories (it's for a quiz), like sports, history and science. So I want the wheel to spin to one of the catagories (random)

Comment: I would like to see how did u hadle all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSTimer to spin the wheel. when you tap the image, it'll trigger timer to start rotate it,

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "rotateWheel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func rotateWheel() {
    //set your angle here
    self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
}
```

and when you want to stop rotating wheel. You can just call below,

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot

Comment: Sure.   @Joaquin van Loon

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to rotate image of the wheel. Use sample code that use `transform` property of the image and rotate it for 180 degrees.

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
      self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
 })
```

Comment: Warning: this will animate a single rotation and then it will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Once I've done very similar job before. Even it was not in `swift`, I believe it will not be difficult for you to try.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = (CABasicAnimation *)[view.layer animationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
NSNumber *toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (M_PI * 2 * round) + [animation.toValue floatValue]];
CGFloat duration = round / speed;

CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.fromValue     = animation.toValue;
rotationAnimation.toValue       = toValue;
rotationAnimation.duration      = duration;
rotationAnimation.cumulative    = YES;
rotationAnimation.autoreverses  = NO;
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
rotationAnimation.fillMode      = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotationAnimation.additive      = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount   = 1;

[view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

You can set `toValue` to stop rotation as you want.